# Help to calculate heat dissipation on plastic dual in line DIP package (DIP-8 opamp)

Tags: operational-amplifier, temperature, heatsink, dip, dissipation

Question is about maximum chip heat dissipation (and not about efficiency or correctness of this design).

Circuit is quite simple: put in parallel 30 Dual Opamps in 8 pin DIL package (i.e 60 opamps in parallel in unity gain configuration) to pilot 4ohm load. For each opamp there is a 5 ohm resistor (Rout) at their output to avoid they fight each other.

Vin is a sine wave of 1KHz (about 12 VACmax)
In theory 12VAC on 4ohm would be 36W @ 3A
This split by 60 opamp, means roughly 600mW @ 50mA load each opamp.

R=4ohm

No Chip=30

No OpAmp=60

RShared= 4ohm * 60 opamp = 240ohm

Rout single = 5ohm

RL = RShared + Rout = 240 + 5 = 245ohm

So I suppose each opamp will be current-like loaded by 245 ohm. (Correct?)

Then I need to calculate package dissipation for a DIL 8 pin plastic package:

Tj Max  = 150°C

OJA = 130°C/W (8-LEAD PDIP PACKAGE) from datasheet

Current max (from datasheet) for each opamp is

IS Max  = 8.7mA

Vs+ = 15V

Vs- = -15V

PSupply Max each opamp= (15 + 15 ) *8.7 = 261mW

Datasheet says (pg 10): "worst case power dissipation occurs at the maximum supply current and when the output voltage is at 1/2 of either supply voltage
(or the maximum swing if less than 1/2 supply voltage)".

For each amplifier PDMax is:

PDMax each=

= PSupply Max + (Vs+/2)^2/RL

= 261mW + 230mW = 491mW

For total chip (dual op-amp):

PDMax chip= PDMax each * 2 = 982mW

TJ Chip: Tj= TA + (PDMax * 130 °C/W) = TA + (0,982 * 130) = TA + 128°

TA Max = Tj Max - 128° = 150° - 128°= 22° (<< 70°C !!!)

As my ambient temperature is 25° or even above, **any heatsink on the DIP 8 chips would not work, and will my amplifier smoke in any case**??

I really need to change the Op-amp or increase the number of op-amp or give up to this project?

Is this correct?
Are all above assumptions correct?
Many thanks.

[**THIS IS THE LINK TO THE DATASHEET**](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/13645fa.pdf)

[image: parallel opamp]

Comment: 150°C is an awfully high junction temperature for reliable operation, especially in a plastic package. More like a storage temperature. Please link the proposed op-amp datasheet. What is your proposed maximum ambient temperature around the PCB?

Comment: The datasheet was already linked in blu at the end of the message. Chips are mounted on socket and the air in the case will be aroud 40 (max 50) degree I can think. No fan will be included. Thanks

Comment: I did read your opening statement, but still, could you provide the rationale for such a design? In particular, why did you choose that opamp and what problem are you trying to solve? This will improve the question and make it more useful for other people browsing the site. It will also open the way for some more general answers.

Comment: (7.5)^2/245 <> 57mW

Comment: You should also be calculating things at the RMS values.

Comment: I re-edit, but how calculate at the RMS values?

Comment: If your 12V pk-pk use 12/sqrt(2) as your average voltage ~8.5V. It wont make a huge difference though. 6.5^2/245 = 172mW average plus that awful 261mW = 433mW

Comment: That helps and means a TAmax of 37°. Maybe the amplifier can survive with the heatsink at 30°C in the enclosure?

Comment: @GianlucaG I hope you have a good fan in that enclosure or it will just be an oven.

Comment: I did a simulation on LT Spice and it gives me 298mW disspation per amp, ie 596mW per chip...much lower than 866mW..Hope this is will result more correct than above math...

Comment: LTspice says maximum power dissipation is 328mW per op amp at ~10V peak = 7.07Vrms sine wave input. Note that the op amp starts to clip at ~13.5V peak input, so the maximum possible sine wave output is ~9.2Vrms (with 287mW dissipation per op amp).

Comment: LTspice is a little more conservative as it considers a quiescent typical current of 6.3mA (pg3 of datasheet), thus a Power dissipation of 189mW per opamp only (instead of 261mW max) with no AC signal. So simulation is correct if according to average/typical values. By using these, plus a RMS power dissipation of 172mW average, we would get 361mW (722mW in total) that means a TAmax of 56° which looks to be achievable with an heatsink. The project looks still alive, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this math is it works in theory, but in practice it may be widely off.

The math only works if all 60 op-amps work exactly in unison. That is a big ask. Any propagation delay in the input signal from the first to last op-amp will create a standing wave of higher current through the devices. Moreover, variances in gain and slew rate from device to device will cause hot spots in your array. These effects will also add distortion into your resultant output signal.

These are the reasons we do not typically double up (or more) devices to increase current drive.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your supply current number is a bit low (9mA is the maximum from the datasheet, 8.7mA is for +/-5V). So that's 18mW more, so a couple degrees C more heating.

If you work to the absolute maximum 150°C junction temperature the numbers work out for a maximum ambient of about 65°C. If your device will never have to work in a temperature (around the chip) higher than that, and if the thermal resistance **in a socket** is 130°C/W then you are fine. [TI suggests](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva509a/snva509a.pdf) a 5-10% derating for socketed parts which is cutting it closer. There will be some rise due to any enclosure as well.

On the other hand if this is only going to be used for AC signals your average dissipation will be considerably less. The above number is for the somewhat pathological case of a DC signal held at the exact worst-case output voltage.

A heat sink can't hurt (well unless it becomes unstuck and shorts something) and it could keep the junction temperatures down a bit, and further away from that absolute maximum limit of 150°C, improving reliability.

Comment: I took 8.7mA +/-15V in page 4 as the supplier did in page 10 in the example. Thanks

Comment: Except @GianlucaG messed up this math = 0.261 + (7.5)^2/245  = ~490mW per half.

Comment: Ohh sh1t !!! You are right. And in fact something sounded strange but I didn't realize where. I have completely re-edit, but now I have a dramatic problem since I don't see any solution. Now I really need an extra help to solve it, as I think that the heatsinkwill not help. Correct?

Comment: Ah, crap- wait he has 980mW Isn't that correct? Aavid has a slip-on heat sink claimed 30 deg C/W for dip-8. One of those expensive anisotropic sheets to a single heatsink might work but would require testing with thermocouples. A linear array, not X-Y is preferred perpendicular to natural convection.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany still, I suspect this could be an XY problem, unless it is a proof of concept that opamps can be paralleled. I prompted the OP to give more hints about why he is doing this, but got no response. The 4 ohm load smells of loudspeaker and the working frequency is in audio band. Could this be an attempt to build a siren sidestepping proper power amp design?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Well it's his business (more or less) but I suspect it's an extreme audiophile audio amplifier. Thirty $5 chips per channel would fit there and it's actually not insane- my Agilent function generator uses a few amplifiers in parallel for 50R output Z. Of course a reactive load may raise other questions outside the scope of this one.

Comment: Yes this will be my personal 10W personal homemade audio amplifier. Will pilot 8ohm loudspeaker normally but 4 ohm simulation is the worst case. I will use a mix of two different video opamp of which I already know and like the musicality.

Comment: Can you please suggest if it will be better use thirty Aavid 580100B00000G 30C/W (one per chip) or two heatsink FISCHER 81/50/SA 3C/W with thermal pad (one per every 15 chips)??

Comment: I don't have a crystal ball as to which would end up being better. The °C/W favors the Aavid which is specified (under some specific set of conditions...), but there are a lot of variables- such as whether the heat sinks are exposed or not, their orientation and so on. If you can't or don't want to do testing and can have the heat sinks exposed the Aavid would likely be a safer guess. The die is not all that well coupled thermally to the epoxy surface- the leadframe is where the heat usually comes out.

Comment: Sorry to bore you again but to calculate heatsink effect I need to know which is the Rjc junction to case value in C/W for the above plastic DIP8. Can I assume 40-50 C/W?

Comment: Look at similar packages eg. CS2842A says 52 K/W.

Comment: Well, I think I finally come to the end. Let us assume Rjc = 52C/W. I will use two heatsink (100mm*90mm*17mm) of 1.7C/W covering every 15 devices (or 30 opamps) with thermal pad (0.34 C/W). Worst case according to supplier formula is to dissipate 980 mW per chip. So:

T.amb= 55°C in close enclosure still air
T.heatsink= 55°C +0.98*15*1.7 C/W= 80°C
T.case= 80°C +0.98*15*0.34 C/W= 85°C
T.junc= 85°C +0.98*52 C/W = 135°C = 90% T.junc max !!

Comment: Sounds good  (pun intended).